# How to tell if I'm using 802.11AC?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, 802.11

I have an ASUS USB-AC53 wireless adapter, with a Netgear 6300v2. The speeds are OK. There is 2 drywall walls separating the computer from the router, and only about 20ft. The signal strength and all is fine, but in Windows when I view the wireless connection I'm connected to it says `Radio Type: 802.11n`. I'm not sure if it is just displaying that because AC is new technology, or if it is actually using 802.11n.

When I right click the connection and click Status, the speed is usually at `117.0 Mbps`. I thought it would be faster than that. Also, using the internet for multiple purposes on this computer such as playing an online game, while downloading a movie just doesn't work. The connection on the game would be very laggy. I thought 802.11AC would be able to handle that?

Anyways, I'm looking for a way to diagnose if I am using AC or N, and ways to improve the network speeds if possible.

Answer (score 2):

On my Linksys WRT1900AC I had the 2.4 GHz and the 5 GHz network SSIDs set with the same name, and my Surface Pro 3 and Lumia 950 XL, both capable of connecting to the 5 GHz band, kept connecting to the 2.4 GHz band.

I added -5GHz to the end of the network SSID on the 5 GHz band and manually connected my Surface Pro 3 and Lumia 950 XL to that network SSID. Now Windows shows that I am connected to 802.11ac, and my speed showed as high as 866.5 Mbps through 2 drywall walls.

Protocol:   802.11ac
Network band:   5 GHz
Manufacturer:   Marvell Semiconductor, Inc.
Description:    Marvell AVASTAR Wireless-AC Network Controller

I assumed Windows would automatically choose the better of the two bands, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if your router is AC and if you are on 2.4 GHZ or 5 GHZ. At 2 GHZ max. speed is around 150 Meg/sec which is N. At 5 GHz you can lock on up to 867 Meg/Sec then you are at AC level. Remember AC is only good at 5 GHz. I have not been able to go higher than 867 Meg/Sec on a wireless plug-in adapter.

Comment: 11n on the 2.4 GHz band is perfectly capable of full 11n speeds, i.e. 600 Mbps (on supported hardware). That being said, both of the OP’s devices are 11ac-capable. But, in general, 5 GHz range is abysmally bad.